# Float left div shifts to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm using css to float my divs left of each other, which gives me 3 rows and 3 columns as I need. But for some odd reason the first div in the second row is pushed under the 2 column in the second row instead of the first column.

Here is a photo example.

[image]

here is the html/php used.

```html
<div class="medium-8 column fourth-post-wrap">
  <div class="medium-8 fourth-post-img">      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('fourth-post'); ?>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post-inner">
    <h1 class="fourth-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <span class="fourth-by-line"> BY: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
    <span class="category-fourth"><?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/category/' . $cat->category_nicename . '">'; echo $cat->cat_name; echo  '</a>'; ?></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css.

```
 .fourth-post-wrap {
 max-width:385px;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px 10px 20px 20px;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-top:2px solid #c7363b;
 }
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Comment: That's because the first item of the first row is higher than the other items. There's one more row of text on it.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour of floats. Don't use floats for layout, it's not for this purposes. Use `display: inline-block` instead

Comment: You may also want to look into using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: inline-block doesn't work @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: I am not familiar with flex box, but It seems complicated as I'm trying it. It's not doing much better with flexbox so far @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: @TerrellAnderson There are many, many tutorials out there. Some of them are really good.

Comment: I'm not liking flexbox so far because it messes with my images. It shrinks my images when i use `display:flex;` and ignores the width it's suppose to be. Even if i place 100% width for images.

Comment: @TerrellAnderson `display: inline-block` **removing** `float:left` works perfectly.

Comment: can u provide the float code? and are have all the divs the same dims?

Comment: some of the divs have different heights but the heghts aren't that much bigger. It depends on the length of text. @AhmedSuror

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it didn't work for me

Comment: @TerrellAnderson may be this is it -the problem- when you float all the divs to a specific direction all the divs -as I do- should have the same dims to look organized, and for example if you need the div to hold more space for more text you can use a scroll bars for the div to hold as many text as u wish by using `overflow: scroll`

Comment: I don't scrolling is visually compelling for that lol. @AhmedSuror But is there not a way with css to align the rows no matter the height of a div above it.

Comment: @TerrellAnderson : may prepare an example for u soon :) ... after work hours

Comment: I would very much appreciate that @AhmedSuror

Comment: Just clear float after every row. clear:both as the height of the first image is more than other 2 so the new element in second row shifted. Clear float before every row will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

try to Remove float Property & Add display:inline-block

```
.fourth-post-wrap {
    max-width:385px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top:2px solid #c7363b;
}
```

Comment: Actually, in these times use flexbox (with flexbox wrap property) to recreate that kind of grid which will then also be more responsive (due to flexbox grow/shrink properties).

Answer (score 0):

Give me a min-height property.

like this

`.fourth-post-wrap { 
         min-height:350px; /*approximately*/
}`